# If we don't assign returned value from method will we still increase memory usage?

Tags: java, memory

For example,

if method returns huge amount of data like:

```
Data[] data = getData(); //will return 100Mb. Java memory usage increased by 100
```

if we call getData without assigment to data, will java will use this 100Mb anyway?

```
getData(); //returns huge data but we don't assign it to var. Memory usage wasn't increased
```

Comment: Yes, but it will be garbage collected soon. If you did not receive a memory overflow.

Comment: `b` => `bits` and `B` => Bytes. e.g. if you have a `1 Gb/s` network card it is one giga-bit per second, not byte. I assume you mean `100 MB`

Comment: Notice that the JVM might remove any unneeded allocations and/or method invocations, provided they do not have side effects, as part of runtime bytecode optimization. But you should not rely on that.

Comment: If applicable, you could implement a custom List<Data> that creates the items on the fly, inside get(). This way, you would not have to store all of them in memory. Unfortunately, this is not applicable in most cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `Data[]` data is simply a reference to the data. So it will use the 100MB.

However if you don't assigned the returned data to any variable **and it don't have any other references**, the data will be quickly garbage collected and memory freed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes the data will be called even if we dont assign it to any variable. Variables are used only to have a reference to the value.

example:

Using variables

```
Object a = getData();
otherFunction1(a);  //calling any other using variable reference
```

Without Using variables

```
otherFunction1(getData());  //calling any other using variable reference
```

The difference is that we have no reference to the value of getData(). Therefore if we have any other function say otherFunction2 we can pass the values as:

For example 1:

```
otherFunction2(a)
```

For example 2

```
otherFunction2(getData()) //need to recall the function getData()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The assignment itself does not use any memory, creating those objects does. So if your method creates a 100MB object, then this memory requirement will not be reduced. But if you don't assign it, it will be garbage-collected soon thereafter (unless it is retained elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Discarding objects will not increase memory usage, it can only decrease it.  This is because the memory used after a GC is that of objects which are referenced.  Less referenced objects mean less memory used.

BTW 100 MB of PC memory costs about $0.30 and is reusable, so not that "huge" IMHO.